# How do I Download the Symfony Distribution as Zip archive?

Tags: symfony, download, zip

I am trying to download symfony since 2 hours, but I can't find a zip to download.
I can't use composer on my network that's why I want a zip. I have gone a lot of time to the download chapter on the symfony web site but I can't find any zip of the lts version. Only the evaluation package is available in zip.
I am going crazy!

Comment: The documentation says [*You can also download an archive of the Standard Edition*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#option-2-download-an-archive) but there is no link to download it...

Comment: Yes I have seen it, but where can I find trustable link?

Comment: The problem is that even if you can download the [Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard), the `vendor/` directory will be missing.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try to add the vendor by myself.

Comment: (I forgot to say that there is a [*Download ZIP* link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/archive/master.zip) on the previous page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony Standard Edition

Download it here
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard

WARNING: This distribution does not support Symfony 4. See the Installing & Setting up the Symfony Framework page https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html to find a replacement that fits you best.

Answer (score 9):

Please check bellow link

http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.6.0.tgz

Or

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/archive/2.6.zip

Note : Don't forget to change your version

For Latest 3.1.0 Version Links

http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_3.1.0.tgz

or

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/archive/3.1.zip

Above links I have given 2.6.0 and 3.1.0 versions , You can change your suitable version , I thought this one help you , Happy Work :) ...

Using command

```
php symfony new my_project_name 2.6.5

or

composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.6.5"
```

More information please check official documentation
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: Can you please forward the 2.1.7 Version Link Please

Comment: Hey please find the bellow link http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.1.7.tgz

Comment: Using command :php symfony new my_project_name 2.1.7

or

composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.1.7"

php app/console assets:install web --symlink

php app/console server:run

Comment: hi, I was looking to download symfony 3.4 WITH the **vendors** folder and when tried your links, the ones from github provide vendor-less zip files (weigh around 50KB) and the links from symfony.com just won't load at all, could you help me find symfony standard version 3.4 WITH vendors? thanx

Answer (score 6):

you should download the zip from the official Git-Repo at:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard

The dl link is in the lower right corner.

Comment: there is no vendor in this one .. and it is version 3 no?