# Where can i find a hyperlink to symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony-2.7

I can't download the zip file symfony2.7.  The link on the website doesn't work.  Does anyone know why? Where can i find the symfony 2.7-zip file? I found an older version somewhere on the internet but i would really like the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really MUST have a zip : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/archive/2.7.zip

also, a simple search would have revealed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102740/dowload-symfony-zip-archiche)

Wich is where i got this answer form ..    so yea,   use search next time ...

Comment: Thank u. Next time i will search a bit more intensive. I'm sorry to upset you.

Answer (score 0):

use the symfony installer, as documented on their website [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)

snip

> **Linux and Mac OS X Systems**:
>
> Open your command console and execute the
>   following commands:
>
> `sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony`
>
> `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony`
>
> This will create a global symfony command in your system.
>
> **Windows Systems**:
>
> Open your command console and execute the following
>   command:
>
> `c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`
>
> Then, move the downloaded symfony file to your project's directory and
>   execute it as follows:
>
> `c:\> move symfony c:\projects c:\projects\> php symfony`

snip

You can then use it to install a specifi version using

```
symfony new my_project_name 2.x.x
```

Comment: For windows i get an access denied error. I use netbeans so i want the zip file.

Comment: then just use plain composer to install symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#creating-a-symfony-application-with-composer

Answer (score 0):

I always used to install it through or via the create-project command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name
```

If you want a 2.7 version

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name '2.7.*'
```

if there is no 2.7 stable version at the time of this writing, you need to lower the stability to dev:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name '2.7.*' -s dev
```

-s (--stability.)